# Cascading drop down lists using Ajax on an MVC4 ASP.NET application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application that stores information about a Job in a database. I'm working on the form to add the information, and three of the attributes that are needed are the Company, Division, and Organizational Unit. A Division belongs to a Company, and an Org. Unit belongs to a Division. With this relationship in mind, I wanted to have three drop down lists for each, where the Division list will be dependent on the Company that was selected, and the Org. Unit list will be dependent on the Division that was selected.

I've tried to implement it using Partial Views with AJAX that are refreshed whenever an option is changed in a drop down list. I'm able to get the Division list refreshed whenever the Company selection is changed, however the Org. Unit list remains unchanged whenever the Division selection is changed.

See below:

Here's the script to handle the change requests:

```
$(function () {
    $('#SelectedCompanyID').change(function () {
        // when the selection of the Company changes, get the new value
        var value = $(this).val();

        // and send it as AJAX request to the newly created action
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DivisionDDL")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { companyID: value },
            success: function (result) {
                // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the ddl container with
                // the partial HTML returned by the DivisionDDL controller action
                $('#divisionDDLContainer').html(result);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#SelectedDivisionID').change(function () {
        // when the selection of the Division changes, get the new value
        var value = $(this).val();

        // and send it as AJAX request to the newly created action
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OrgUnitDDL")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { divisionID: value },
            success: function (result) {
                // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the ddl container with
                // the partial HTML returned by the OrgUnitDDL controller action
                $('#orgUnitDDLContainer').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the portion of the form that is used:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCompanyID, Model.ListCompany)

<div id="divisionDDLContainer">
@Html.Partial("DivisionDDL", Model)
</div>

<div id="orgUnitDDLContainer">
@Html.Partial("OrgUnitDDL", Model)
</div>
```

Here are the partial views:

OrgUnitDDL:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModelJobDetails
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrgUnitID, Model.ListOrgUnit)
```

DivisionDDL:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ViewModelJobDetails
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDivisionID, Model.ListDivision)
```

Here are the methods in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult DivisionDDL(string companyID)
    {
        ViewModelJobDetails vm = new ViewModelJobDetails();
        vm.lDivision = Maintenance.GetDivisionList(companyID);

        return PartialView(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult OrgUnitDDL(string divisionID)
    {
        ViewModelJobDetails vm = new ViewModelJobDetails();
        vm.lOrgUnit = Maintenance.GetOrgUnitList(divisionID);

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

I tried seeing if the functionality of the Org. Unit list would work on it's own (by taking out the first part of the AJAX request and filling the Division drop down list with all of the values regardless of the Company chosen) and it works. But when I have the two requests together, only the Division functionality works.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be going wrong?

**UPDATE:** After more testing, I realized that if I leave the Company drop down list unchecked and select a Division from the drop down, the Org. Unit list will populate as intended. But as soon as I change the Company, the functionality of the Org. Unit list will go away but the Division list will populate as intended.